# wp submodule update to 4.7.2 - Unable to checkout

Tags: wordpress, capistrano, git-submodules

I am trying to update my wp submodule to 4.7.2 (I use capistrano to deploy).

I am able to update locally but when I deploy to staging or production I get the following error:

```
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: From github.com:WordPress/WordPress
9bf3844..d333018  master     -> origin/master
fatal: reference is not a tree: 1ea8e9a4f03f425a6a77c3487528fedd3f33c100
Unable to checkout '1ea8e9a4f03f425a6a77c3487528fedd3f33c100' in submodule path 'wordpress/wp'
```

But that tree must exist for it to be working locally right?

Any ideas of what direction I should be looking in? Or better yet a solution!

Thanks
N

Comment: I bet you've forgotten to `push` the changes in your submodule.

Comment: Hi @ThibaultD. I thought that too but the commit is in my repo: `-Subproject commit c840eb9da2ef1c7a23d3ec2d63c0d953fed56926
+Subproject commit 1ea8e9a4f03f425a6a77c3487528fedd3f33c100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to delete my repo from the server and then redeploy. Seemed to have an issue with the submodule in the Capistrano routine.

THanks